# Is a block linked to its parent in a proof-of-stake blockchain?

Tags: blockchain

In a proof-of-work based blockchain, each block contains a reference to its parent, making it impossible to modify one block without having to mine again all of its descendants.

Now in a proof-of-stake algorithm, how would a situation like this be prevented as there is no complicated hash to compute for each block? Is a block even linked to its parent?

Answer (score 1):

In Ethereum, there are more than one tree structure: `Transaction Trie`, `World State Trie`, and `Transaction Receipts Trie`. These trees are together formed to prove the validity of the block. If miners want to determine if the block is valid, they check those trees.

Every block header in ethereum contains those:

> • State root: The state root field contains the Keccak 256-bit hash of
> the root node of the state trie. It is calculated once all
> transactions have been processed and finalized.
>
> • Transactions root: The transaction root is the Keccak 256-bit hash
> of the root node of the transaction trie. The transaction trie
> represents the list of transactions included in the block.
>
> • Receipts root: The receipts root is the Keccak 256-bit hash of the
> root node of the transaction receipt trie. This trie is composed of
> receipts of all transactions included in the block. Transaction
> receipts are generated after each transaction is processed and contain
> useful post-transaction information. More details on transaction
> receipts are provided in the next section.

Proof of Stake does not change the block structure of the blockchain, it does change the validation process of the block. I gave the example of Ethereum as POS but Merkle tree structures (or different variations) are used in blockchains extensively because they are efficient and fast for the verification of large datasets.